# How to fix Windows Server 2012 time goes back 1 hour after reboot?

Tags: time, windows-server-2012-r2, ntp, domainservices

We have two domain controllers with windows server 2012 R2. My Timezone is set to +3:30 and I disabled the daylight savings. Daylight savings will add 1 hour to current time but I want it to be unchecked and add 1 hour manually to current time. After server reboot or a while my time goes back 1 hour!! NTP is disabled, Windows Time service is disabled. Why I can't set my clock manually?
I unplugged PDC from network and added 1 hour and reboot. the result was Ok. This shows that when PDC boots, it syncs clock with somewhere. How can I disable this?
Please help, My entire domain clock is in wrong time.
Thanks

Comment: I'm sure time sync is *required* for it to be a PDC (Kerberos etc) have you checked the event viewer for anything related to the time changing, and have you tried to set the clock at hardware (BIOS etc.) Also why do you want the time in your domain to be wrong anyway? (as in +3:30 but no dst)

Comment: Our timezone is +3:30 Tehran, Daylight saving will add an extra hour for the first 6 months. I tried to set clock in bios but after booting windows, it came back 1 hour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to disable the external time source to stop updating system time.
you have two [ways](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc794937%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) to fix this,

```
w32tm.exe /config /manualpeerlist:"127.0.0.1" /syncfromflags:manual /reliable:YES /update
```

or go to regedit

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\W32Time\Parameters]
```

"NtpServer"="127.0.0.1"

this way you guarantee that your system have no external time source.